# Laravel - multiple similar routes

Tags: laravel, routes

Having some systems, each system has a separate controller, I tried this:

```
Route::get('/system/{system_id}', 'system_one_Controller@index')->where('system_id', '1');
Route::get('/system/{system_id}', 'system_two_Controller@index')->where('system_id', '2');
...
Route::get('/system/{system_id}', 'system_n_Controller@index')->where('system_id', 'n');
```

but obviously, only the last line is applied, i.e /system/n
All the routes before the last line, like /system/1, return "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

I know I can use a simple line like:

```
Route::get('/system/1', 'system_one_Controller@index');
```

but, some systems share the same page and I want to use the system_id parameter within the views. e.g.

```
/system/1/users
/system/2/users
```

both routes will use a common view, that will determine the system using system_id parameter

I also prefer to use separate controllers for each system, as each system may have a lot of sub pages like:

```
/system/1
/system/1/users
/system/1/posts
/system/1/post/{post_id}
/system/1/post/{post_id}/comment/{comment_id}
```

and other systems may have totally different sub pages with different routes (and may also have similar routes and common views as I said before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two options I can see

first do this:

```
Route::get('/system/1', 'system_one_Controller@index');
Route::get('/system/2', 'system_two_Controller@index');
```

or second do this:

```
Route::get('/system/{system_id}', 'system_Controller@index');
```

and in the index function in controller do if or switch:

```
if ($system_id === 1){

} else if ($system_id ===2){

}
```

edit:

If you want to use a different controller for every index, then you must have a different route for every index. (So the first option I mentioned)

And if you have a different controller for every system, why not hardcode the index of that system as a static property in that controller or something similar? You don't need it passed as a parameter to the controller, because it isn't dynamic.

Comment: thank you, but both answers will not be the best for me, see question update.

Comment: alternatively you could use a single controller with dynamic index property... and then call some function from within the controller. But why do it there and not in your routes file?